# Jquery parameters of dom elements

Tags: jquery, html

I want to write an own jquery function which do some stuff on all dom elements which has a specially class tag.
But some elements should have some specific animations. Thats why i want to declare some parameters inside of the dom elements like that:

```
<div class='animate' animate-speed='0.5' animate-dir='up'></div>
```

Is it possible and if yes how i can get the parameters by jquery.

Comment: try $('.animate').attr('animate-speed');  and  $('.animate').attr('animate-dir');

Comment: i tried console.log($('.animate').attr('animate-speed')); the console said undefined. console.log($('.animate')); works fine

Comment: i figured out. i have to use equal instead of colon. sorry my mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use data-attributes.

> HTML5 is designed with extensibility in mind for data that should be associated with a particular element but need not have any defined meaning. data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard, semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or Node.setUserData().

HTML code :

```
<div class='animate' data-speed='0.5' data-dir='up'></div>
```

*notice : you can't to use ":" but "="*

JS code :

```
$('.animate').each(function() {
    // acces to attrbiutes, jquery method
    console.log($(this).attr("data-speed"));

    // or javascript method
    console.log(this.dataset.dir); // not with the word data-
```

});

Example :

try this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/btwqtLsj/1/)

Comment: thank you a lot. now i use equal and everything works fine!

Comment: Ok, I do a JsFiddle for you. (post Edit)